# How to Create CRON Jobs that Require SUDO Permissions

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I'm on Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo). I've added my regular user acc. in SUDOERS and only use root when I'm bound to.

Now, I've created a basic script to automate my updates and free up some space. It looks like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#LOGS = /home/rubaiat/updates.log
#logs are enabled by aliasing, see alias
echo -e "\n$(date "+%d-%m-%Y ---  %T") --- Starting \n" 

apt-get update
apt-get -y upgrade

apt-get -y autoremove
apt-get autoclean

echo -e "\n$(date "+%T") \t Script Terminated"
```

I've enabled **x** permission for this and can run this by:

```sh
$ sudo ./sys-maintainer.sh 
[sudo] password for rubaiat:
```

I've refrained from adding sudo inside the script, as I'd be required to store the password in plaintext.

I've created an alias as:

```sh
alias sys-maintainer='sudo ./sys-maintainer.sh >> updates.log 2>&1 && tail -7 updates.log'
```

Now I can just type

```sh
$ sys-maintainer 
[sudo] password for rubaiat:
```

..and run my script alongside storing the terminal outputs into a simple text file. My idea was to grep this file for the desired info whenever I require it.

Now, here goes the problem-

As I don't want to invoke this script manually, I wanted to put it into CRONTAB. But the problem is, I can't designate jobs that require SUDO into my regular user's CRONTAB, as the process will pause asking for the password.

I know I can do this from my root account's CRONTAB. But I don't want to go that way unless its the only one.

So, how can I add my script inside the CRONTAB of my regular user? Bear in mind that it requires SUDO for executing the atomic commands.

I understand that I might be missing some standard/key techniques. It'd help if anyone can shed some light onto these matters as well.

**NB:** Thanks if you read this. I know its kinda long. Also, it's my first post here; so hopefully I didn't do anything inappropriate.

Comment: Adding these jobs to `root`’s `crontab` is the correct solution. Why don’t you want to use it?

Comment: 1. I'm not sure about the updates taking place given I don't log as root during the scheduled period.  2. I'm curious to know how can I set this manually.

Comment: You should probably not discard the output then but redirect it to your mail address, using `MAILTO=someuser` or even `MAILTO=your@mail.com`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm redirecting the output to a file as of now. I can grep it and check whether everything  went as I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've created a basic script to automate my updates and free up some space.

You've reinvented the [unattended-upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html) service.

> But the problem is, I can't designate jobs that require SUDO into my regular user's CRONTAB.

Well, you can – just add `sudo` to the command.

However, since cron cannot prompt you for the password, you need to designate those commands to be *passwordless* through `/etc/sudoers`. This line would allow cron to `sudo` your script:

```
rubaiat ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/rubaiat/bin/sys-maintainer.sh
```

(Note: in sudoers, the last match wins. So make sure to add such exceptions at the end of /etc/sudoers, or in any case *below* the generic "ALL=(ALL) ALL" lines.)

Comment: Thank you! So, if I change the value from 1 to 7 in this line `APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";` apt will download them once a week?

Comment: So, I've appended `rubaiat ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/rubaiat/sys-maintainer.sh` to /etc/sudoers and scheduled a cron as `10 22 14,27 * *  sudo ./sys-maintainer.sh >> updates.log 2>&1`